# CSS stacking not working. z-index stuff

Tags: css, z-index

So I am trying to get some things to stack on top of each other. First of all it would help to see the working link and you'll see the issue:

**http://brownbox.net.au/clients/matchlessphotography/**

Now I need to use the folloing code:

```
<div id="blogposts">

        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>
        <a><span><strong class="title_blog_mini_post">Post Title</strong></span><img src="images/wp-evential/sample-blog.jpg" width="197" height="134" /></a>

    </div>
```

and have the span sitting directly on top of the image, at the bottom so that when it animates within the jQuery it looks like the great overlay slides down to just under half the size and the post title text pops up.

Now I am almost there but its not working.
What CSS do I need to fix to do this? Here is the current css:

```
#blogposts{width:100%; height:auto; margin-left:8px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:30px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } 
#blogposts a{border:1px solid #141414;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;border-radius: 12px; margin:10px 18px 9px 5px; width:197px; height:134px; display:block; float:left;} 
#blogposts img{-webkit-border-radius: 11px;width:197px; height:134px; -moz-border-radius: 11px;border-radius: 11px; margin-top:0px; float:left;} 
#blogposts span{z-index: 1000;float: left;bottom:-146px; width:177px; height:114px; background-image:url(images/misc/picoverlay.png); -moz-border-radius: 11px;border-radius: 11px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); padding:10px; font-size:18px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-style:italic; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #141414;}
```

Comment: I heartily recommend [Mozilla's primer on stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context) - which certainly helped me understand how they work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Z-index will only affect an object with a position set to "absolute" or "fixed".
By default, a position is set to "relative" and will simply ignore the "z-index" css property.

Comment: z-index also affects elements relative positioned

Comment: -1 Completely and utterly wrong. Not only does `z-index` indeed affect relatively-positioned elements as @FabrizioCalderan states; the default value of `position` is *not* `relative` either - it's `static`.